# QProcess::startDetached blocked by UAC (running an updater)

Tags: qt, process, uac

I have an update function in my app - it downloads and verifies the installer (a setup.exe, created with NSIS). To actually kick off the update, I have simply been doing:

```
QString path = .. absolute path to the downloaded file ...
QProcess::startDetached(path, QStringList());
```

This works fine on XP - but on Vista and Win7, nothing happens once the download completes. If I browse to the downloaded update and run it manually, it works fine. I assume what's happening is that UAC is blocking the installer at CreateProcess time, but this is where my knowledge runs out.

Additional complication - when I'm running a debug build from the command line, the steps above work - I get the UAC prompt and can run the installer. It's the release builds, started form the start menu/shortcut, which have the issue - I assume there's a difference in the auth token when running from a command shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not admin and you call CreateProcess() on a .exe with a "Vista" manifest (or no manifest, but a .exe that windows detects as an installer (This includes NSIS)) the call fails, you need to use [`ShellExecute[Ex]()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). ShellExecute will trigger UAC prompt if required...

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
```

Might be surprising and counterintuitive, but it works and is more cross-platform

Comment: Awesome solution. This actually call ShellExecute in the background. The only problem I see is that it does not bring the UAC window to the top

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a Qt bug, see [QTBUG-9761](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9761) , the correct workaround is to use `ShellExecute` with `lpOperation` set to `runas`.

Comment: Using the runas verb will _force_ UAC elevation, if you don't specify a verb, ShellExecute will figure it out on its own...

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to prepend your execution with `cmd.exe /C`. This effectively routes your execution through the shell, so you do get the UAC prompt. The downside is that if your process fails you probably won't get as much information had you gone through `ShellExecute[Ex]`, but on the plus side you will get all the facilities of `QProcess` that you miss if you use `QDesktopServices::openUrl`, where you have no idea if things worked or not.