# Using Qt to open external game application

Tags: windows, qt

I have a windows qt application and I'm trying to open an external game, but I'm not having success.

Application is in C:\games\Oni\Edition\ and is called Oni.exe, the code I'm using right now is the follow:

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    qint64 test=1;
    if(!QProcess::startDetached("Oni.exe",QStringList(),"C:\\games\\Oni\\Edition\\",&test)){
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Oni couln't be started!");
        msgBox.exec();
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm forgetting something? The game runs fine if I double click it. Thanks.

Comment: What is your version of Windows? Do you have UAC enabled?

Comment: The version is Windows 7 professional. Yes I believe UAC is enabled, I tried other applications like "cmd.exe" with the code above and works just fine.

Comment: remember that the UAC has more than just one setting and has multiple rules to evaluate if an executable needs the attention of an admin, you can't test your application just testing 2 or more executable because they can have different rules for the UAC.

Comment: Tried ShellExecute tip by user827992 `ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "Oni.exe", NULL, "C:\\games\\Oni\\Edition\\", SW_SHOWNORMAL);` and worked fine. However it doesn't ask for UAC privileges.

Comment: the fact that UAC does not ask for privileges does not mean that UAC is not checking your request; also Vista and Windows 7 both have UAC enabled by default but they comes with different default settings, 7 has more "silent" UAC settings than Vista, i suggest to just test your application in each one of your targeted environment and if you use some exe that is not local for the user, just assume that UAC is on.

Comment: you can also write your solution as an answer to this question :)

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks. Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, figured it out.

Just replaced the code:

```
QProcess::startDetached("Oni.exe",QStringList(),"C:\\games\\Oni\\Edition\\",&test)
```

by

```
QProcess::startDetached("C:\\games\\Oni\\Edition\\Oni.exe",QStringList(),"C:\\games\\Oni\\Edition\\",&test)
```

And it's working like a charm.

I had also tried `QProcess::startDetached("C:\\games\\Oni\\Edition\\Oni.exe");` before but didn't worked, seems we need to put always the full directory of the executable and also the full directory as working directory. **This** because seems only executing the file directly, the file itself may be looking for another folders/files in the QT Debug folder, when they are in the game folder. This cause the game quits prematurely. :)

Another solution would be use windows native api like user827992 pointed out in the follow link: [QProcess::startDetached blocked by UAC (running an updater)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526787/qprocessstartdetached-blocked-by-uac-running-an-updater)

This latter solution also should work fine with UAC problems.